# Modify jquery UI classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This works:

```
$(".myClass .ui-widget-content, .myClass").css( {"background-color": gBkgColor, "color": gFontColor});
```

I am able to manipulate the properties of the widget header easily with the Firefox inspector like so:
[image: firefox inspector screenshot]

I do not know how to do it with the proper syntax. For example, the following pieces of code are ineffective:

```
$(".myClass .ui-dialog-titlebar, .myClass").css ({"background": "", "color": "blue" });
$(".myClass .ui-widget-header, .myClass").css ({"color": "blue" });
```

What would the proper syntax be to yield the same results as those in the screenshot, i.e. an 'empty' widget header?

IMPORTANT: **just edited** the following two lines — much better results but I still cannot get rid of the overall 'background' property.

```
   $(".myClass .ui-dialog-titlebar").css ({"background": "", "color": "blue" }); // ineffective
   $(".myClass .ui-widget-header").css ({"background": ""}); // ineffective
  $(".myClass .ui-widget-header").css ({"background": "red", "color": "blue" }); // effective but insufficient
```

Comment: you forgot the dots for the class selectors e.e.g `.ui-widget-header` instead of `ui-widget-header`

Comment: .css with 1 argument returns the value of the selector's property I believe.

If given 2 arguments, ie .css('background-color', 'blue')  this will change it.

Comment: @ADyson — That is true. I am going to edit my post — but it remains ineffective.

Comment: @simon — Indeed. But what about the widget header background property?

Comment: select the widget header then.

$('.ui-widget-header').css('background-color', 'blue');

Comment: @simon http://api.jquery.com/css/ one of the versions of the method allows the first (and only) argument to be an object of property-value pairs to set, so in theory the syntax shown, with the correct selectors, should work.

Comment: yes you're right.  I don't typically use it this way though, but thats personal preference.

1 argument to retrieve, 2 to set is how i use it.

Comment: Additional info. This does not work: $(".Aide .ui-dialog-titlebar").css ({"background-color": "yellow", "color": "blue" }); while this does: $(".Aide .ui-dialog-titlebar").css ({"background": "yellow", "color": "blue" });

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer, but this should work given that your selector is accurate.

```
$('#myselector').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nr2uanuk/

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am dealing here with jQuery UI selectors. What I am driving at is to get rid of the widget header background. Can you please be more specific with your answer?

Comment: does this not work?

$(".myClass .ui-widget-header, .myClass").css ('background-color', 'blue');

Comment: jquery ui selectors are no different than any other dom element.  i use jqui quite frequently and if i need to make one bigger or color it for a various reason, .css is a great way to go if you dont want to define a ton of different classes.

Comment: if you want to completely get rid of the background:

$('#element').css('background-color','transparent');
or
$('#element').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');

Comment: Thank you for your involvement. I shall get back to you later today.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
$(".myClass .ui-dialog-titlebar").css ({"background": "url('')"}); // etc…
```

Actually one can see from my previous comments with simon and others that, at least with jQuery UI's .ui-dialog-titlebar element, css detailed property descriptors such as

```
$(".myClass .ui-dialog-titlebar").css ({"background-color": "pink"});
```

will not work. (Never mind the object notation —it *is* valid, should it contain  one property only.)

As far as .ui-dialog-titlebar is concerned this contradicts jQuery .css() API: only shorthand notation is effective. I have no further explanation for it and comments are welcome.